# How to set a color for a specific range of values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with a huge range of numbers.  I want to be able to set a color for a specific range of values.  If it falls between 0 to 20% it should be red then 21 to 40% it should be blue and on so on.

I have tried some code but it is returning some NULL values and i don't understand why.  How do I fix this?

```
WITH cte  as 
(
   SELECT 
       [% APL Population],
       ([% APL Population] / NULLIF(Max([% APL Population]) OVER(), 0) ) * 100 AS [% APL PopulationPercent] 
   FROM   
       dbo.Indicators) 
SELECT 
    [% APL Population],
    [% APL Populationcolor] = 
       CASE 
          WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN 'red' 
          WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] BETWEEN 21 AND 40 THEN 'blue' 
          WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] BETWEEN 41 AND 60 THEN 'green' 
          WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] BETWEEN 61 AND 100 THEN 'purple' 
       END 
FROM cte
```

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Error in between you miss value from 20-21, 40-41 and so on. Using Between you create gap, interchange to > and <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BETWEEN you create gap between values. You need to use comparison operators.

Try this:

```
WITH cte([% APL Population],[% APL PopulationPercent])
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [% APL Population]
        ,[% APL PopulationPercent] = ( [% APL Population] / NULLIF(Max([% APL Population]) OVER(), 0) ) * 100 
    FROM   dbo.Indicators
)
SELECT 
    [% APL Population],
    [% APL Populationcolor] = CASE 
           WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] >= 0  AND [% APL PopulationPercent] < 20 THEN 'red' 
           WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] >= 20 AND [% APL PopulationPercent] < 40 THEN 'blue' 
           WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] >= 40 AND [% APL PopulationPercent] < 60 THEN 'green' 
           WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] >= 60 AND [% APL PopulationPercent] <= 100 THEN 'purple' 
           ELSE 'unknown'
    END
FROM  cte
```

Comment: The Null values were replaced with "unknown" but I need the values to fall with in a range so that I can give it a color based on the range.

Comment: Does APL Population return also NULLs?

Comment: No there is a value for APL Poplulation, if you look at the image in the question you will see.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `between` in this scenario.

```
WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] < 20 THEN 'red' 
WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] >= 20 AND [% APL PopulationPercent ] <40 THEN 'blue' 
...
```

Issue was because 20.5 is grather than 20 and less than 21. Then don't match any `case` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your CASE expression doesn't account for fractional values that fall between ranges.  Try an inclusive begin and exclusive end range like the example below, modifying for the buckets you want.

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   [% APL Population]
                      , ( [% APL Population]
                          / NULLIF(MAX([% APL Population]) OVER ( ), 0) )
                        * 100 AS [% APL PopulationPercent]
               FROM     dbo.Indicators
             )
    SELECT  [% APL Population]
          , [% APL Populationcolor] = CASE WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] >= 0 AND [% APL PopulationPercent] < 20
                                           THEN 'red'
                                           WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] >= 20 AND [% APL PopulationPercent] < 40
                                           THEN 'blue'
                                           WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] >= 40 AND [% APL PopulationPercent] < 60
                                           THEN 'green'
                                           WHEN [% APL PopulationPercent] >= 60                                             THEN 'purple'
                                      END
    FROM    cte
```